# How to get URL hit by browser in C# application

Tags: c#

Actually, my requirement is, when a user type a URL in any browser like example.com?q=123 and hit go then my C# application will verify request and fetch the value of q.

any solution for this???

Comment: This program already exists.  It's called [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: What did you do yourself?? Any code to show we don't design and create your code....

Comment: Actually, my requirement is, when a user type a URL like http://example.com?q=123 and hit go then my C# application will verify request and fetch the value of q.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You will have to hook your application to somehow track all outgoing requests over port 80 and 443

Comment: Can you plz share some code example of it...